# Firebase multifactor authentication "non" SMS based

Tags: firebase-authentication

So there are good tutorial on how to enable multifactor using sms as the 2nd factor. https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa

I am finding (and yet could not find), if I don't want to use sms but create my own custom 2nd factor.

Let says a user can login using email/password, then it will throw error that two factor is required (sure he must have enrolled into custom multifactor first), and I will send some code to user "telegram or fb message or whatsapp", and he need to provide the code to finish authentication.

Sure that I need to enroll user for custom multifactor first.

Is it possible? and how I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many things (including adding custom authentication factors) are possible, given that Firebase Authentication is just based around tokens that you can [mint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) and [manipulate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) yourself in server-side code. Giving you a step by step recipe or implementation is a bit beyond the scope of what we can reasonably do here on Stack Overflow, but the links should provide a good starting point.